# Is there a way to copy the content of a hyperlinke file to my clipboard?

Tags: excel, vba

Well, I have a several standart texts that I use in my work. I have them listed in hyperlinks in a excel workbook, but I was thinking if there is a way to copy the content of this texts files without openning the files (what the hypyerlink does).

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways of doing this. 1) Simply mouse over the first hyperlink and left-click copy down to catch all links, right click Copy, then paste in Notepad or similar.
2) Click the header of the hyperlinks and highlight entire section, right click and select "Remove Hyperlink". At that point you could easily copy the entire hyperlink list and paste elsewhere. Please advise if this helps. If not, I'll think of something else.